# Previous/next record based on search result

Tags: php, postgresql, pagination, paging

### Some background

The system in question has some ten thousand records which the user is allowed to browse or search through a "massive" array of different search criteria. The result is then displayed in a paginated table ranging from a few pages to every result in the database.

If the user has made a lot of filtering and ended up with a result and clicks an arbitrary record she is then taken to a new view `/edit/{record_id}` where she can view all the details of said record. It's easy to go back to the last search result at any time, as the criteria is retained in the search bar, but:

### What I'm trying to achieve

If the user is to do a lot of changes based on the search result, it would be *very* convenient with previous and next buttons to access the adjacent records without returning to the result.

I've been able to do this on a basic level using `id`s

```sql
SELECT table.*, pn.p as previous_question, pn.n as next_question
   from table,
   (
       SELECT id, lead(id) OVER w as n, lag(id) OVER w as p
       FROM table
       window w as (order by id $order)
   ) as pn
   where table.id = $id
       and pn.id = $id
```

This obviously only works for the simplest of cases where the records are in the same order as in the database. What I want is for them to work in *every case* of data order. Needless to say, the are nearly infinite ways to sort this data.

### What I've been thinking

**Create some kind of function/tool** that will let me keep the SQL from the search and perform it again like above, only with search criteria and offset in stead of `id`s

**Save a list** of the order of all the records in the result, either in the `$_SESSION`, database or somewhere else, and then simply traverse the list to get the `id`s I need.

### Tools at hand

PHP, PostgreSQL, JS/jQuery.

### TL;DR

I want to be able to get to the next search result without returning to go back to the search, no matter how many times the user clicks "next".

## ----------

Any input would be appreciated. Links to relevant articles, ways to approach this or even the whole shebang ;). It would also be nice to be able to solve this without eating all the servers memory, or excess db access, although resources aren't really an issue here.

Comment: Why dont you use session or cookie like you suggested? It is a good solution and will work.

Comment: Well, it's an option. I just don't find it to be very elegant with an array containing potentially 50k items. On the other hand, I might just be over thinking this. That's why I wanted some input :)

Comment: Pagination is normally done through use of multiple queries using the sql LIMIT command.

Comment: You could save search history in your database and just save the unique identfiers in your session / cookie. That is how some other sites does it.

Comment: @MatthewMcGovern Since I'm paging one and one item, you suggest my first approach is best?

Comment: @jurgemaister i didnt mean you were suppose to save the array of results! Just the sql query. Just save the different query settings not the result!

Comment: You would store a lower and upper index in the session (in your case, it would be the same I guess), the next/prev buttons would simply increase/decrease the index. Your SQL would then have a LIMIT lowerindex, upper index. You could easily store the whole SQL query the user has built up too. I would NOT recommend storing the entire returned array in the session as it means you have to do the data processing in PHP when you should do it in SQL.

Comment: @MatthewMcGovern all right. What you said and Adams answer prooobably put me on the right path. I'll go do some programming, and then come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just going to throw it out there... You should use **Solr** or something similar particularly if this a [SAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) and exposed to many users.

Basically trying to keep track of a paginated search result and then traversing will cause lots of state management in your app.

The idea with Solr (or even just plain postgres) is to do a start and size for your search (aka **OFFSET** and **LIMIT**). Solr does this so fast its hardly a performance problem. Just make sure for Solr or Postgres you do a predictable sort by (aka **ORDER BY**).

If your worried about new items being added throwing off the pagination thats simply a: `WHERE create time stamp is less than when we did the initial search`.

Comment: Solr seems really interesting, and a quite powerful tool indeed. I'm afraid it's outside the scope of this application though as it is intended for an administrative interface used by only a handful of users. Thus, setting up a Java server is overkill.

Comment: My other comments still apply though. Just use LIMIT and OFFSET plus WHERE CREATE TIME STAMP IS LESS THAN ... and a predicatable ORDER BY.

Comment: Ah. Think I got what you meant. So by e.g. repeating the search with limit 3 and offset n-1 I would get the current, previous and next records.

Comment: Bingo! and I'm going to say some random stuff so that I meet the minimum for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I see a bunch of possible issues here.  The big one is you are trying to map stateless HTTP requests to stateful database operations, and you are trying to do this as statelessly as possible.

I think the elegant solution REST-wise is to use navigation buttons (back esp) and drill-down to get to the specific detail records.  In this way you can persist the basic results in the client, namely the browser cache.

In this way you'd have to use the back button to get back to the (possibly paginated) summary search results but you wouldn't have to hit back to get to the search criteria.

Comment: As I come to think of it, it's kind of already stateless. I throw in all search parameters to populate the search bar, so I could easily just pull them out again to perform the query. I do agree that it's the most semantic way to do it, but I decided to go with storing the last performed search query in the session as it just is a lot easier. Yay laziness!

Comment: It's not just a question of what is easier.  Part of the problem is that persisting result sets like this across a session esp when you have to add limit and offset to each new query eventually will have significant performance implications.  If you have a simpler system of "send a list of the results to the client and let them see what they want to follow up on" then you avoid this and get to do a single record lookup probably on the primary key on each details page they look at.

Answer (score 0):

Store the search context, including the selected filters, query and sort order. Optionally store them hashed by content so you end up with a unique list of search contexts.

Include a link to the saved search context in the link to the detail page, using a hash of some sort.

On the detail page, retrieve the search context via hash and do two additional searches, one going forward in the same direction, the other going backward. Do this by swapping asc and desc in your sort order definition.

In both cases, limit the results to 1 record, and add an additional clause that ensures that the current detail record is not included.

This should give you the correct records for previous and next links.

A more detailed answer for Elasticsearch can be found here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42384125/401467

Answer (score -1):

There aren't that many solutions for this problem.

1 - Because your query is dynamically built, you have either to persist criterias and perform the query every time providing LIMIT ... OFFSET or directly a result_id (using the row_number window function in a `WITH` clause).

2 - You can persist directly the result set in the server, I do not advise to use the session to store such amount of data.

3 - Or you can persist the Collection on the client, sending the whole result set in Json and browse it with a Javascript like angularjs or backbonejs. I guess if you return 10k rows, this will be very slow too.

I'd suggest 1 or 3.