# Get neighboring results for an ElasticSearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to get nearby results for ElasticSearch query?

**Example 1**. If I have items, named as:

```
one
two
three 
four
```

then search "three", ordered, for example, by name, ascending, should return something like (given number of neighbors is 1):

```
one
*three*
two
```

**Example 2**. I have query results and ID of an document in it, I want IDs of next and previous document. The order is set in query.

Comment: What does for you mean "neighbors"? What is the order of these elements?

Comment: Ordering is what I set in query. Edited question.

Comment: Hm, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42384125/401467